# Python inequalities: != vs not ==

Tags: python, operators

I realized today while writing some Python that one could write the inequality operator as `a!=b` or `not a==b`.  This got me curious:

1. Do both ways behave exactly the same, or are there some subtle differences?
2. Is there any reason to use one over the other?  Is one more commonly used than the other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. `==` invokes `__eq__()`. `!=` invokes `__ne__()` if it exists, otherwise is equivalent to `not ==`.
2. Not unless the difference in 1 matters.

Answer (score 10):

Be mindful of your parenthesis.

```
>>> not "test" == True
True
>>> not "test" and True
False
```

`==` takes precedence over `not`. But `not` and `and` have the same precedence, so

[Python Operators Precedence](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

Comment: Are you sure?  `not 'test'==True` evaluates to True, whereas `(not 'test')==True` evaluates to False, so it seems like `not a==b` evaluates to `not (a==b)`.

Comment: I was using AND when I was playing around with the statement.

Comment: This answer is `not True == True`